# Can I use an article before a proper noun at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

It is told that we do not use any article if there is a proper noun. So, could I use an article before a proper noun if it is located at the beginning of a sentence ?

For example- Att chemical method is a good method for making a drug.

Could I use 'The' before Att chemical method ?

Comment: As Jeff Morrow said, the rule that you learned is not quite correct.  It's not "Don't use an article before a proper noun, ever", it's "don't use an article if a proper noun is the subject or object."  In this case, *method* is the actual subject of the sentence, and *Att* is an attributive noun that modifies it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, you should say either

> Att’s method

or

> The Att method

The name “Att” in the second version is essentially acting as an adjective to identify a specific method. The fact that the adjective is derived from a proper noun is irrelevant to the grammar of the sentence, in which “method” rather than a human being is the subject.

The purported rule that you learned is too simplistic.

> The Republic of India is a member of the United Nations

is a sentence containing two proper nouns, each preceded by an article.

This is a complex subject. For a simple introduction, start with

http://writing.umn.edu/sws/quickhelp/grammar/articlesproper.html